# Telnet session vs TCP session

Tags: java, sockets, session, tcp, telnet

What's the difference between a `TELNET` and `TCP` session?
I have a simple server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555);
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");
    InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
    out.writeUTF("\u001B[2J");
    out.writeUTF("Hello client\r\n");
    while (true) {
        int b = sin.read();
        sout.write(b);
    }
}
```

I'm connecting via telnet and typing like this:

[image]

So I assume that packet sending by telnet client has no specific headers and pass to low level protocol (`TCP` in my case) completely without changing. Is it correct?

Comment: This code won't work anyway. It attempts to write ANSI escape codes with writeUTF(), which writes a length word before the string. The terminal won't understand the length word.

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_data:

> All data octets except 0377 are transmitted over the TCP transport as is. Therefore, a Telnet client application may also be used to establish an interactive raw TCP session, and it is commonly believed that such session which does not use the IAC (0377 character, or 255 in decimal) is functionally identical.[citation needed] This is not the case, however, because there are other network virtual terminal (NVT) rules, such as the requirement for a bare carriage return character (CR, ASCII 13) to be followed by a NULL (ASCII 0) character, that distinguish the telnet protocol from raw TCP sessions.[clarification needed] On the other hand, many systems now possess true raw TCP clients, such as netcat or socat on UNIX and PuTTY on Windows, which also can be used to manually "talk" to other services without specialized client software. Nevertheless, Telnet is still sometimes used in debugging network services such as SMTP, IRC, HTTP, FTP or POP3 servers, to issue commands to a server and examine the responses, but of all these protocols only FTP really uses Telnet data format.
>
> Another difference of Telnet from a raw TCP session is that Telnet is not 8-bit clean by default. 8-bit mode may be negotiated, but high-bit-set octets may be garbled until this mode was requested, and it obviously will not be requested in non-Telnet connection. The 8-bit mode (so named binary option) is intended to transmit binary data, not characters though. The standard suggests the interpretation of codes 0000–0176 as ASCII, but does not offer any meaning for high-bit-set data octets. There was an attempt to introduce a switchable character encoding support like HTTP has,[3] but nothing is known about its actual software support.

I would type some more but really Wikipedia covered it nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

Telnet is a name of services. and TCP is protocol to connect computer together with reliable, ordered, error-checked delivery of a stream.